# MongoEngine Query Optimization

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have two collections `ScenarioDrivers` and `ModelDrivers` which has One to Many relationship with each other.

```
class ScenarioDrivers(Document):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'ScenarioDrivers'
    }
    ScenarioId = ReferenceField('ModelScenarios')
    DriverId = ReferenceField('ModelDrivers')
    DriverCalibrationMethod = StringField()
    SegmentName = StringField()
    DriverValue = ListField()
    CalibrationStatus = StringField()
    AdjustedValues = ListField(default=[])
    CreateDate = DateTimeField(default=ObjectId().generation_time)
    LastUpdateDate = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())

class ModelDrivers(Document):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'ModelDrivers'
    }
    PortfolioModelId = ReferenceField('PortfolioModels')
    DriverName = StringField()
    CreateDate = DateTimeField(default=ObjectId().generation_time)
    LastUpdateDate = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())
    FieldFormat = StringField()
    DriverData = ListField()
```

My query is like this.

```
class GetCalibratedDrivers(Resource):
    def get(self, scenario_id):
        scenario_drivers_list = []

        scenario_drivers = ScenarioDrivers.objects(ScenarioId=scenario_id).exclude('ScenarioId').select_related(1)
        for scenario_driver in scenario_drivers:
            scenario_driver_dict = {
                'id': str(scenario_driver.id),
                'DriverId': str(scenario_driver.DriverId.id),
                'SegmentName': scenario_driver.SegmentName,
                'CalibrationMethod': scenario_driver.DriverCalibrationMethod,
                'CalibratedValues': exchange(scenario_driver.DriverValue),
                'AdjustedValues': scenario_driver.AdjustedValues,
                'LastUpdateDate': formatted_date(scenario_driver.LastUpdateDate),
                'FieldFormat': scenario_driver.DriverId.FieldFormat
            }
            scenario_drivers_list.append(scenario_driver_dict)

        return {
            'DriverCalibrations': scenario_drivers_list
        }
```

The Query matches `1140` records and then I construct a dictionary and make it a list.

But this API call takes `30s` to process just `1140` records. Where I am missing? Please help. I am using latest version of Pymongo and MongoEngine.

Comment: Do you have an index on `ScenarioDrivers.ScenarioID` field?

Comment: I haven't defined any indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with your query, it is with you looping over 1140 records. I do not see any use of referenced objects so you should consider removing `select_related(1)`. Once you do that, if you want to convert reference object ids to string, you can use `as_pymongo()` which will do that by default for you. And finally if you must read some data in specific format like `formatted_date` or `exchange`, it is better to save them as part of your document. i.e. save `FormattedLastUpdateDate` with `LastUpdateDate`. In MongoDB, you have to think about your read specific logic when you save the document.